# Proof that when the conditional mean of Y does not depend on X, Y and X are uncorrelated

Tags: correlation, covariance, conditional-expectation

I've been struggling to understand the proof that when E(Y|X) = $µ_y$, then cov(Y,X) = corr(Y,X) = 0, as provided in Stock and Watson's Introduction to Econometrics, 4th Edition. The book says the following:

First, assume Y and X have a mean 0, cov(Y,X)=E(YX). Second, the law of iterated expectations states that E(Y) = E[E(Y|X)]. Then, using this law, E(YX) = E[E(YX|X)] = E[E(Y|X)X] = 0, because E(Y|X) = 0, so cov(Y,X) = 0.

The specific parts in this sequence I struggle with are:

- E[E(YX|X)] = E[E(Y|X)X]; I don't understand why the conditional mean of YX is equal to the conditional mean of Y, multiplied by X.
- Why E[E(Y|X)X] = 0 means cov(Y,X) = 0.

I do understand on an intuitive level why the correlation should be 0 when the conditional mean of Y is equal to the mean of Y. I just don't understand this proof, probably due to the way it's denoted.

Comment: @kjetil b halvorson: Why did you edit my post? I can't say "Thanks in advance"? I'm honestly baffled by your action.

Comment: Because:  On this site there's no need to say "thank you" at the end 
of your post - it might seem rude at first, but it's part 
of 
[the philosophy of this site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) 
to "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions", and it 
means future readers of your question don't need to read 
through the pleasantries.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why the conditional mean of YX is equal to the conditional mean of Y, multiplied by X

Note that when $X = x$ we have that
$$E(YX | X = x) = E(Yx | X=x) = x E(Y | X=x).$$
We can say that when $X=x$ the random variable $E(YX | X)$ takes on the value $E(Yx | X=x)$. But, we can also say that when $X=x$ the random variable $E(YX | X)$ takes on the value $x E(Y | X=x)$. Consequently, the random variable $E(YX | X)$ must be the same as $X E(Y | X)$.

Suppose, for example, that the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are both continuous and that the conditional probability density function of $Y$ given $X=x$ is denoted by $p(y | x)$. Compare
$$
E(YX | X=x) = \int_{\mathbb R} yx \, p(y | x) \, dy \quad (*)
$$
and
$$
x E(Y | X=x) = x \int_{\mathbb R} y \, p(y | x) \, dy \quad (**).
$$
You should notice that they are equal.

> Why E[E(Y|X)X] = 0 means cov(Y,X) = 0.

Given the assumptions you've made, it follows that $\text{cov}(Y,X) = E(YX)$. Since it's also true that $E(YX) = E[E(Y|X)X]$, if $E[E(Y|X)X] = 0$, then $\text{cov}(Y,X)=0$ because they are equal.